# C++11 implicit copy constructor while implementing explicitly a constructor

Tags: c++11, constructor, copy, move, implicit

I ran into a problem. I implemented a constructor for a class, but why are implicitly generated the other constructors, like the copy one?
I thought, that if I define a constructor explicitly, then the compiler doesn't generates implicitly other ones. I'm really hoping, that this a VC++ specific thing, and that this code doesn't conforms to ISO:IEC C++11:

```
class Foo
{
    int bar;

public:
    Foo(int&& arg) : bar(arg) { cout << "RConstruction" << endl; }
};

int main(int, const char*[])
{
    Foo f = Foo(42);

    /* Create unused temporary on the stack */
    Foo::Foo(f); /* calling Foo::Foo(const Foo&): this shouldn't work... */

    return (0);
}
```

Please keep in mind, that this is a sample code, created exactly for this situation, for demonstration purposes, I expect answers only that strictly relate to this question.

Comment: That's not a move cosntructor, so it doesn't suppress any implicit ones.

Comment: Question corrected. Thanks!

Comment: g++ says `error: cannot call constructor ‘Foo::Foo’ directly` and clang sees it as a declaration - `error: redefinition of 'f' Foo::Foo(f); `. But it is correct if you instead do `(Foo(f));`.

Comment: @zch You can't refer to a constructor like that. §12.1/2 "A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type. **Because constructors do not have names, they are
never found during name lookup**; however an explicit type conversion using the functional notation (5.2.3)
will cause a constructor to be called to initialize an object. [ Note: For initialization of objects of class type
see 12.6. — end note ]"

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a move constructor, so it doesn't suppress any implicit ones.

Just like `Foo(const int&)` isn't a copy constructor, `Foo(int&&)` isn't a move constructor, it's just a constructor taking an rvalue reference.

A move constructor looks like one of:

```
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(const Foo&&)
Foo(volatile Foo&&)
Foo(const volatile Foo&&)
```

> I thought, that if I define a constructor explicitly, then the compiler doesn't generates implicitly other ones.

If you define any constructor the compiler doesn't generate the *default* constructor, but it still generates the others.  Define the as deleted if you don't want them:

```
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not declare a move constructor, but a regular constructor : no implicit constructor will be deleted.

A move constructor would be of the form `Foo(Foo&& arg)` (with any cv-qualifier on the argument)

Also note that this statement is not valid C++ :

```
 Foo::Foo(f);
```

Maybe you meant :

```
Foo g = Foo(f);
```

Comment: This is why I hate VC++: it compiles anything, without any warnings... Thanks!